# If $p$ is a prime, then $S_{p-1}$ has no element with order $kp$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

How can I prove the statement:

> If $p$ is a prime, then $S_{p-1}$ has no element with order $kp$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

I don't know what is the best approach, I've tried to use permutations, but I can't proceed. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that the order of each element in a group must divide the size of the group? If so, then the existence of such an element means that $kp$ divides $|S_{p-1}|=(p-1)!$, and therefore $p$ divides $(p-1)!$, but since $p$ is a prime, it does not divide the product of any numbers less than it (such as $(p-1)!$), and we have a contradiction.

Comment: Another way to approach this problem is to recall that the order of a permutation is given by the lcm of the lengths of its disjoint cycles, and clearly the lcm of numbers smaller than $p$ cannot contain a factor $p$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of $S_n $ is $n!$.  By Lagrange the order of any element would divide $(p-1)!$.  But $kp\nmid (p-1)!$.